# G Suite のアカウントで YouTube にログインできない

Tags: youtube, gsuite

G SuiteアカウントのメールアドレスでYouTubeにログインしようとすると「YouTubeへのアクセス権がありません。組織の管理者にアクセス権の付与を依頼してください。」と表示されます。解決策を教えて下さい。
またログインが可能になった場合の変更内容/影響も教えて下さい。

Answer (score 2):

表示されたメッセージに従って **組織の管理者にアクセス権の付与を依頼してください。**

G Suite の管理者は、所属するユーザーがどのように YouTube にアクセスできるかを任意に設定できるようです。

なんらかのルールに則った制限かと思われますので、正当な理由でアクセスが必要なのであれば、まず管理者に確認を行ってみてください。

**参考:**
[ユーザー向けに YouTube を有効または無効にする - G Suite 管理者 ヘルプ](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6304948?hl=ja)